# phpmyadmin doesn't load database since php.ini was changed

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpmyadmin

I needed to change my php.ini file yesterday as my project won't run properly without changing `zend.script_encoding =` to `zend.script_encoding =utf8`. Since then I have not been able to load my database on phpmyadmin without undoing the change. Any idea why this is happening and what can I do to avoid it?
The loader appears as "loading?" instead of "loading...". I don't think thats relevant but I'm mentioning it anyway.

Comment: Probably better to use `declare(encoding='UTF-8');` in your script. Instead of making it a server wide setting

Comment: @tlenss , I already had declare(encoding='UTF-8'); in my base ui class when this issue began. I don't think its related to that.